# Подключить плагин таймера

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Помогите пожалуйста подключить плагин таймера на страничку. Я все нужные библиотеки подключил и добавл контроллер к моему модулю. Пример [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/gusmjrjy/3/).
Сам плагин взял [отсюда](https://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/index.html#)

html:

```
<div ng-app="HelloUserApp">
    <div ng-controller="HelloUserController">
        {{qw}}
    </div>

     <div class="enter-screen-inner" ng-controller="countdownController">{{timerRunning}}
        <timer countdown="10041" max-time-unit="'minute'" interval="1000">{{mminutes}} minute{{minutesS}}, {{sseconds}} second{{secondsS}}</timer>

        <timer end-time="1475488800000" language="ru" finish-callback="timerFinished()">
            <div>
                <div>{{days}}</div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div>{{hours}}</div>
            </div>
        </timer>
    </div>          
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('HelloUserApp', [])
    .controller('HelloUserController', function($scope) {
        $scope.qw = 'qwerty';
    })
    .controller('countdownController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.timerRunning = true;

        $scope.timerFinished = function () {
          console.log('timer is finished');
        };
    });
```

В консоли ошибок нет, но время всё равно не показывается на экране. В этом проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В приведенном коде не используется сам плагин.

Для его использования, в зависимости основного модуля нужно добавить модуль плагина:

```
angular.module('HelloUserApp', ['timer'])
```

Кроме того, плагин зависит от momentjs, поэтому нужно добавить ссылку на эту библиотеку

```js
angular.module('HelloUserApp', ['timer'])
  .controller('HelloUserController', function($scope) {
    $scope.qw = 'qwerty';
  })
  .controller('countdownController', function($scope) {
    $scope.timerRunning = true;

    $scope.timerFinished = function() {
      console.log('timer is finished');
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-timer/1.3.4/assets/js/angular-timer-all.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="HelloUserApp">
  <div ng-controller="HelloUserController">
    {{qw}}
  </div>

  <div class="enter-screen-inner" ng-controller="countdownController">{{timerRunning}}
    <timer countdown="10041" max-time-unit="'minute'" interval="1000">{{mminutes}} minute{{minutesS}}, {{sseconds}} second{{secondsS}}</timer>

    <timer end-time="1475488800000" language="ru" finish-callback="timerFinished()">
      <div>
        <div>{{days}}</div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div>{{hours}}</div>
      </div>
    </timer>
  </div>
</div>
```